# Using a method to change object reference values

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

This is a PDFSharp question, but I think it falls more correctly into the range of how object referencing works in vb.net.

So I have code that looks like this:

```
Dim page as PdfPage = pdf1.AddPage()
Dim graphics as XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
```

So this naturally creates the graphics XGraphics and PdfPage objects that I need.

Now when I need to add pages to the PDF document I'm creating, I call the code:

```
page = pdf1.AddPage()
graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
```

Of course, there are other things I do as well, such as add XTextFormatters, define my starting X, Y coordinates, etc. But suffice to say that being the lazy person that I am, I tried to code a method that would allow me to pass in all the variables I wanted, and automatically update all these for me. So in short, something like:

```
Private Sub ConductPrinting()
    Dim pdf1 as New Pdf
    Dim page as PdfPage = pdf1.AddPage()
    Dim graphics as XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)

    'Printing code here
    'Printing code here
    'Printing code here

    'Start new page code
    pdfPage = pdf1.AddPage()
    graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
End Sub
```

I want to write a `StartNewPage()` method, something like:

```
Private Sub StartNewPage(pdf1 As Pdf, page As PdfPage, graphics As XGraphics) As Integer
    pdfPage = pdf1.AddPage()
    graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
End Sub
```

So that the code block can look like this instead:

```
Private Sub ConductPrinting()
    Dim pdf1 as New Pdf
    Dim page as PdfPage = pdf1.AddPage()
    Dim graphics as XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)

    'Printing code here
    'Printing code here
    'Printing code here

    'Start new page code
    StartNewPage(pdf1, page, graphics)
End Sub
```

How would you go about doing this? Because this doesn't work; both page and graphics are still referencing the old page and graphics.

Comment: I think your `page` and `pdfPage` variables/types are a bit mixed up. If they are mixed up in the way I suspect they are, then you need `Private Sub StartNewPage(pdf1 As Pdf, ByRef page As PdfPage, ByRef graphics As XGraphics)` - see [Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Are you using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)?

Comment: The ByRef keyword worked perfectly. I forgot all about it. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the objects you want to change by reference instead of by value, so...

```
Private Sub StartNewPage(pdf1 As Pdf, ByRef page As PdfPage, ByRef graphics As XGraphics)
```

From [Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx):

> **When to Pass an Argument by Reference**
>       If the procedure has a genuine need to change the underlying element in the calling code, declare the corresponding parameter ByRef.